# Change the language in the menus in Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office

I have changed the language to English in Options > Language [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toQ2k.png), but the menus are still in german. How can we change also the language of the menus [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIYpa.png)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will have to provide an English translation for your first and second screenshots.

Comment: I don't know german. That is why I want to change to English. In the first figure you have the language window in excel. In the second figure, you have menu from excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the *editing* language (for grammar, spelling check etc.) to English (USA) as default language.

To get the right language of your menus you have to change your *display* language. (see screenshot - it is marked)

[image: screenshot with marked differences]

The problem is that you do not have installed the English (USA)-Language for your Office version, but you can download it from [Microsoft.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f). Simply choose your language and architecture (32/64 bit). After downloading you have to install the language as you can see in the description.